# Captcha comes out at any time in a test

Tags: cypress, captcha

- I am doing a test in which a capchat can come out at any time but I cannot know the exact moment. I just need to grab it and run my script at that point *

```js
cy.get('.captcha-modal', { timeout: 60000 }).then(($loading) => {
    expect($loading).length > 0

    cy.get('.captcha-modal', { timeout: 60000 }).click({ force: true })
    cy.get('.captcha-modal__content .captcha-modal__question').invoke('text').then((text) => {
        let textop = text
        let finaltx = textop.trim()
        let finaladd = 0
        let newtext = finaltx.split(" ")
        if (newtext[1] == '+') {
            finaladd = parseInt(newtext[0]) + parseInt(newtext[2].trim())
            // cy.log(finaladd + " plus")
        } else if (newtext[1] == '-') {
            finaladd = parseInt(newtext[0]) - parseInt(newtext[2].trim())
            // cy.log(finaladd + " minus")
        }
        cy.get('[name="captchaVal"]').first().type(finaladd)
        cy.get("[type='Submit']").click()
    })
})
```

Comment: If it is a test environment, you should consider having captcha turned off.

Comment: I have it deactivated in another environment but this is the production one that I have to try too